# Extract Values from CSV file to then multiply with values from other CSV? Python

Tags: python, csv

I'm very new to programing and using python especially.
I have a CSV file that is 20 by x, and has a variety of probability values. it will look somethign like this:

```
A      B     C    D    E
1      2     3    4    5
6      7     8    9    10
11     12    13   14 ...
```

And I have a second CSV file that is 20 by 1 that looks something like this(I can change this second one to fit what i must do no problem but the first i cannot):

```
  A      B     C    D    E
  1      2     3    4     5
```

Now What i need to be able to do is to read every line of the first CSV file extract the value and multiply it with the respected column. and to them take each row and find the sum of the row. so i would like the output to be:
The first being as followed

```
 A      B     C    D    E
 1x1    2x2   3x3  4x4  5x5
 6x1    7x2   8x3  9x4 ...
```

And the end result being:

```
55
130
...
```

Any and all advice would be much apreciated.
Thank you

Comment: Have you written any code? Take a look at the `csv` module.

Comment: i've treid to write some coad this is what i have so far...but i'm having a lot of trouble with it              with open ('Test.aap') as csvfile:
                        reader=csv.reader(csvfile, delimiter='\t')
                        for row in reader:
                                a=(','.join(row))
                
                
                np.loadtxt(open('Trial.csv','rb'), delimiter='\t')
                R=csv.reader(open('Trial.csv','rb'), delimiter='\t')
                x=list(R)
                results=np.array(x).astype(str('float'))
                print(results)

Comment: Please edit that into your main post with correct formatting. See the [help on formatting](https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help#comment-formatting) if you're not sure how.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's one way that demonstrates using `csv`. It's repetitive and verbose, in hopes it'll give you something to research and test with.

```
#!/usr/bin/python

import csv
import re

file2_list = []

with open('2.csv', 'r') as fh2:
    reader = csv.reader(fh2)
    for row in reader:
        if re.search(r'\d', row[0]):
            file2_list = row
            break

with open('1.csv', 'r') as fh1:
    reader = csv.reader(fh1)
    for row in reader:
        if not re.search(r'[^\d]', row[0]):

            result = [] 

            for i,v in enumerate(row):
                result.append(int(v) * int(file2_list[i]))

            print(sum(result))
```

Input file 1:

```
a,b,c,d,e,f,g,h,i,j
1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10
11,12,13,14,15,16,17,18,19,20
```

Input file 2:

```
a,b,c,d,e,f,g,h,i,j
5,10,15,20,25,30,35,40,45,50
```

Output:

```
1925
4675
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use Pythons csv module to read the csv file, it's documented at:

https://docs.python.org/2/library/csv.html#module-csv

To perform your computation, use numpy if you have much data, since it's fast.
The numbers you are computing are the inner product of each row of your multirow table with the one and only row of your one row table, i.p. is doc'ed at:

http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.inner.html